# how to do a $post simultaneously on a text link?

Tags: jquery

I have :

```
$('.clic').click(function () {
      event.preventDefault();
      var cliclink = $(this).attr('href');
      var clicanchor = $(this).text();
      $.post("addclic.php", { li: cliclink, an: clicanchor });
})
```

and

```
<a href="new_page.html" class="clic">my_link</a>
```

When i click on the link, the `$.post` is done but i'am no redirected to new_page.html.
If i suppress `event.preventDefault()`, i'am correctly redirected to new_page.html but the `$.post` doesn't work.

I'd like the link and the `$.post` work simultaneously, but how ?....

Comment: Just do a redirect in the `$.post` success callback: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/503093/how-can-i-make-a-redirect-page-in-jquery-javascript

Comment: If you follow the link, it reloads the page and all scripts stop. You can't do it simultaneously.

Comment: Take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2694876/jquery-how-to-call-a-custom-function-before-following-link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can redirect using `location.href` and redirect to url in success call back function:

```
$('.clic').click(function () {

event.preventDefault();
var cliclink = $(this).attr('href');
var clicanchor = $(this).text();
$.post("addclic.php", 
{ 
  li: cliclink,
  an: clicanchor },
  function(response){

location.href=clicklink;

});
})
```